# C Linux Macro for "localhost" in sockaddr_in structure?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, localhost

**I prefer *not* doing a resolve**. A quick hardcoded macro to **`0x0100007F`** would work beautifully for IPv4, is there one for IPv6 too?

This is for the `bind()` BSD sockets structure `sockaddr_in6` and `sockaddr_in`

Comment: did you try just this? `0x01000000000000000000000000000000` that is 01 and then 15 pairs of `0`s? Or am I just wrong?

Comment: well, for one, the C compiler doesn't support 128-bit integers natively. It'd have to be an array, was wondering if the headers already contain something though, would make code feel cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

man ipv6 is your friend :)

There is a `in6addr_loopback` variable and for initializations a macro `IN6ADDR_LOOPBACK_INIT`.

Be careful about the macro you want to do for IPv4, don't forget that this is stored in network order, so the endianess of the system is an issue, here.

Comment: @unixman83, no. For IPv4 the whole `127` address range is reserved for loopback. Using `127.0.0.1` is only a convention that most systems follow. In IPv6 there is really only one reserved address.

Comment: Just a question...what is the macro actually declared as? Like in `#define IN6ADDR_LOOPBACK_INIT X`, what is `X`?

Comment: @mtahmed, no idea, and I am not sure that I want to know. This is platform specific, you'd have to look this up in your system header files. It is provided exactly for that reason, programming such things platform independent would be very tedious.